# error C2446: == : no conversion from const char * to TCHAR *

Tags: c++, windows, tchar

I have a TCHAR define below:

```
 TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
```

and I want to comapare as below:

```
if(szProcessName == "NDSClient.exe")
{
}
```

But then I am getting the errors:

> error C2446: == : no conversion from const char * to TCHAR *
>   error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'const char [14]' to 'TCHAR [260]'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"NDSClient.exe"` is a `const char*` string on windows. If you want it to become a `const TCHAR*` then you need to use the `TEXT` macro. Also, you can not compare strings using `==` use a equivalent `TCHAR` function such as `_tcscmp`.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can use. `L"some string"` to make TCHAR*. But I suggest you to use `std::wstring` (analog of `std::string` and as `std::string` needs `#include <string>`) instead of TCHAR*.

example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 wstring s = TEXT("HELLO");
 wstring ss = L"HELLO";
 if(s == ss)
  cout << "hello" << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: L"some string" is a `WCHAR*` not a `TCHAR*`.

Comment: If you're using `std::wstring` then you should just use `wchar_t` everywhere instead of TCHAR. (And by extension you shouldn't use the TEXT macro)

Comment: Also do note that `L"some string"` is not a `WCHAR*`. It is `const WCHAR[12]` :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for usefull comments. It was very helpfull for me.