# What is difference between TCHAR and WCHAR?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've opened winnt.h header file and found there this two lines:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
```

and

```
typedef WCHAR TCHAR, *PTCHAR;
```

but there was comment in one of my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201893/error-c2446-no-conversion-from-const-char-to-tchar/4202751#4202751) that there is some difference between them. Then what is the difference?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you read the entire header, you will find:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef WCHAR TCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

or words to that effect.

Perhaps MS has removed the narrow option of late.

Answer (score 12):

`TCHAR` can be either `char` or `WCHAR` based on the platform. `WCHAR` is always a 16-bit Unicode character, `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 7):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx

TCHAR:

A WCHAR if UNICODE is defined, a CHAR otherwise.

WCHAR:

A 16-bit Unicode character. For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking there is no difference because you cannot typedef two different entities to a single one. Let us See An Example...

```
typedef char a;
typedef char  b;
typedef a b, c;
```

This Definition Works But If a Change The Above Definition To This

```
typedef char a;
typedef char * b;
typedef a b, c;
```

**Error 1   error C2040: 'b' : 'a' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'**

**Another One**

```
typedef char a;
typedef int b;
typedef a b, c;
```

**Error 1   error C2371: 'b' : redefinition; different basic types**

So By Analyzing These Things Only Same Type Can Defined Together.

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` is portable type which is `char` for ANSI type projects and `WCHAR` (16-bit Unicode char) for UNICODE projects. Using `TCHAR` and `TCHAR *`/`LPSTR` you can create portable project which can easily be recompiled for ANSI and UNICODE version. But after Windows 98/ME become obsolete and rarely used, there is no need to create non-Unicode executables.