# Iterating over char* error no conversion from char* to int

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm iterating over a char* as follows, but on the line indicated, I'm getting error C2446 '!=' no conversion from char* to int.

```
        int errorLineNumber = 0;
        char* json;  //this is a long json with multiple \n's in it.
        int offset = errorOffset;
        char* p = json + offset;
        while (*p-- != '\n' && offset--); //check that this gives offset on that error line and not char position of end of last line before error
        errorLineOffset = errorOffset - offset; //get offset on error line only

        //count lines to json error
        long errorLineNumber = 0;
        while (*p!= json) //this is error line
            errorLineNumber += *p-- == '\n';
```

I looked at [conversion const char to tchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201893/error-c2446-no-conversion-from-const-char-to-tchar), but it's a little different, and I also looked at [conversion const char to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303100/no-conversion-from-const-char-to-int), which I still don't think is the same issue, unless I'm missing something.

That would be great if someone had a good idea what I'm missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Show the types of the variables involved.

Comment: Works fine in VS2015

Comment: Don't you mean while (p != json)?

Comment: It's a good idea to include a [mcve]. There's one person requesting more info, one who had it work for however they completed the shown code, and one who took a guess at the problem. None of these would be necessary with an MCVE.

Comment: Which line is giving the error? It is not clear from the comments in the code. You also have several variables that you don't show types for (e.g. `errorLineOffset`, `errorOffset`). Please help us help you by expanding your code to be a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I added error line comment.  I thought I had added that.

Comment: Also, you should be using modern C++ features, like std::strings and iterators. This code is too clever by half and takes way too much effort to understand it.

Comment: I know.  I used to have something more understandable, but my team asked me to change it to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
while (*p != json)
```

you compare a `*p` which is of type `char` to `json`, which, according to the code above should be a pointer, I assume it is of type `const char*. So you should do

```
while (p != json) ...
```